# mkdir relative/absolute path permissions

Tags: permissions, mkdir

I'm currently in a directory `foo` (pwd is `/some/lepath/foo`)

I own `foo`, but not `/some/lepath`. I got here by cd'ing to foo, then `sudo -u`ing to the owner of `foo`, hence I am now in a directory I could not otherwise reach without being put here first.

If I do `mkdir ./bar/` the dir is created fine.
If I do `mkdir /some/lepath/foo/bar/` I get a permission error.

Is there a way to get mkdir (or deps) check pwd to prevent it trying to traverse the full path, and hence hitting this error?

Comment: You cannot change the behavior of `mkdir` when you specify an absolute path. You could use a shell script wrapper that does this check and calls `mkdir` with a possibly modified argument. What are the owner, group and permissions of `/some`, `/some/lepath` and `/some/lepath/foo`? What are the primary group and supplementary groups of user `foo`?

Comment: What's the output of `namei -lx /some/lepath/foo/`?

Comment: @Bodo I have relevant permissions to foo, but not to lepath. What those permissions are, and whether I might inherit them from user/group; the issue is the path through a directory I cannot access, to one that I can. It sounds like this would need patching in mkdir to solve w/o a script workaround.

Comment: @Chris2048 Please [edit] your question to add information instead of answering in comments. It is difficult to answer without more background information. Why do you have such a strange setup of the permissions? You don't need to patch `mkdir`. You could create a script named `mkdir` which calls the real `mkdir` program (`/bin/mkdir`?) and place it somewhere in your PATH before the real `mkdir`. You didn't answer all questions from my and muru's comments.

Comment: @Bodo I believe all the relevant information *is* in the question: I have permissions to foo, but not lepath. I don't consider this setup strange: I'm running a process from via another (more restricted) user from within my home. I could indeed write a script, but that would be the "script workaround", *w/o* which I'd need to patch mkdir AFAIK. If you believe the behavior of mkdir cannot be changed, then that is the answer: but I want to see if anyone knew otherwise before I attempted a patch.

Comment: The reason I'd consider a patch, rather then a script wrapper is that a) is seems to me to be *gotcha* behavior w/ mkdir where I usually otherwise consider abs/relative paths to be equivalent, and  b) because I am not the caller of mkdir, I am calling *another* script which turns all its paths absolute before using mkdir.

Comment: We asked questions because **we think** that the information in the question is not enough. Your question might be an XY problem. Maybe there is a better solution, but without knowing the details it is hard to give a good answer. Why do you need to run the script/program as a different user? Why don't you use a script that does not replace the relative path?

Comment: @Bodo I'm familiar with linux, the real-world problem is already solved. I'm not interested in frame challenges - I'm asking *specifically* because I want to know the capabilities of mkdir. As a question that will be useful for more than just myself, unless you're guaranteed *never* to have this problem, then this question may be relevant to *someone* and so worth answering. AFAIK, this is SEs role as a Q&A site/wiki, versus tech support.